# Real roots of an infinite series consisting of Harmonic number

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

I know that the following equation, as a function of $s$, has two real roots:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{s(1-s)H[n]}=\frac{1-r}{r}e^{s^2}-1
$$
for $0<r<1$. Is there any simple way to find these real roots for a given $r$? Mathematica
takes a long long time to solve it using NSolve, FindRoot, etc. Even worse, for example:

```
r = 0.8;
FindRoot[(Exp[s^2] (1 - r))/r - 1 == Sum[Exp[s (1 - s) HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, Infinity}], {s, 1.6}]
```

gives "the sum diverges" which does not.

Comment: Show what have you tried in terms of Mathematica codes.

Comment: I've forwarded parts of your question to the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995401/infinite-sum-of-harmonic-number-powers) for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this Math.SE solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3995537/632893) to construct a fast approximation of $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{x\cdot H_n}$ as
$$
f(x) \approx f_m(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m e^{x\cdot H_n} + \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} e^{x\cdot[\gamma+\log(n)]}
= \sum_{n=1}^m e^{x\cdot H_n} + e^{\gamma x}\zeta(-x,m+1)
$$
for a large integer $m$:

```
f[x_ /; x < -1, m_Integer /; m >= 1] :=
  Total[Exp[Accumulate[x/Range[m]]]] +
  Exp[EulerGamma*x]*HurwitzZeta[-x, m + 1]
```

we can find the desired roots very fast and accurately:

```
With[{r = 0.8, m = 10^4},
  FindRoot[f[s*(1-s), m] == (1-r)/r*Exp[s^2] - 1, {s, -1}]]
(*    {s -> -1.2183}    *)

With[{r = 0.8, m = 10^4},
  FindRoot[f[s*(1-s), m] == (1-r)/r*Exp[s^2] - 1, {s, 1.7}]]
(*    {s -> 1.68535}    *)
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you so much. @Roman

Answer (score 1):

`SumConvergence` indicates you sum converges for `s` greater than the Golden Ratio, which `s = 1.6` is not.  Use a slightly larger initial value for `FindRoot`:

```
r = 0.8;
sol = FindRoot[(Exp[s^2] (1 - r))/r - 1 == 
   Sum[Exp[s (1 - s) HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, ∞}],
  {s, 2}]
(*  {s -> 1.68535}  *)
```

`FindRoot` now seems to find a root:

```
N[
 (Exp[s^2] (1 - r))/r - 1 - 
   Sum[Exp[s (1 - s) HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, ∞}] /. sol
 ]
(*  9.76996*10^-15  *)
```

The other root, which @user64494 kindly pointed out, occurs in the other interval of convergence, where `s` is less than the conjugate of the golden section.

```
sol = FindRoot[(Exp[s^2] (1 - r))/r - 1 == 
   Sum[Exp[s (1 - s) HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 1, ∞}],
  {s, -1}]
(*  {s -> -1.2183}  *)
```

Comment: Another real root is `s == -1.21830031520808`.

Comment: Yeah, you get convergence for `s` less than the conjugate of the golden section, too. I guess my focus locked in on the OP's code and the problem with it. Thanks.

Comment: `FindRoot[(Exp[s^2] (1 - r))/r - 1 == 
   Sum[Exp[s (1 - s) HarmonicNumber[n]], {n, 
     1, \[Infinity]}], {s, -2}]` finds it. When `RealAbs[s]` is big, then there is no real root there.

Comment: Thank you all. It means that the starting point has to be in the convergence radius??? I did not know the logic behind it. @ user64494 @ Michael E2

Comment: @Farhad If you start `FindRoot` at a point where the function doesn't return a number, `FindRoot` will quit.  So your starting point has to be a value of `s` for which the series converges.