# How can I solve this equation involving an infinite sum of Harmonic number powers?

Tags: equation-solving

```
V[x_] := Exp[x^2] - 1
T[x_, b_] := Sum[Exp[-b*x^2*HarmonicNumber[i]], {i, 1, Infinity}]
Solve[T[x, b] - V[x] == 0, x]
```

Comment: For inserting code, use `{}` icon to insert code in a proper format. line 2 `bx` should be `b*x` and `inf` should be `Infinity`.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide more background. Where did the equation come from? Why do you want to solve it? Do you happen to know when the sum converges?

Comment: The function $T(x,b)$ is computed in [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3995401/632893) and is still not resolved. Set $T(x,b)=f(e^{-b x^2})-1$ with $f$ from that question.

Comment: For a fast way to approximate the function $T(x,b)$ based on $f$, [see this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238640/26598).

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the `SumConvergence`

```
SumConvergence[Exp[-b*x^2*HarmonicNumber[i]], i]
(*Re[b x^2] > 1*)
```

`ContourPlot`helps to visualize solutionpairs `x[b]`

```
ContourPlot[Sum[Exp[-b*x^2*HarmonicNumber[i]], {i, 1, Infinity}] ==Exp[x^2] -1, {b, 1, 3}, {x, 1/Sqrt[b], 1.5},FrameLabel -> {b, x}] // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that the equation under consideration has not a closed-form solution. Therefore,
numeric methods for concrete values of `b` should be used to this end, for example,

```
NMinimize[(Exp[x^2] - 1 - Evaluate[
NSum[Exp[-2*x^2*HarmonicNumber[i]], {i, 1, Infinity}]])^2, x] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{151.796, {2.25349*10^-23, {x -> -0.841565}}}`